# What is the better formatting tool: Intellij Code Style or Prettier

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, prettier

I would like to introduce a code formatting tool into my project in order to ensure a consistent codebase. We all use IntelliJ and Jetbrain products like TeamCity.

I wonder which one is the better tool. Is it possible to integrate IntelliJ Code Style in CI toolchain like Prettier? Which tool is more powerful?

Answer (score 0):

There are instructions on how you can integrate Prettier with [WebStorm](https://prettier.io/docs/en/webstorm.html) and I'm sure it's similar to other JetBrain products.

Comment: My question is not how to integrate Prettier into Jetbrain products. Why should I use Prettier if there are IntelliJ Code Style settings?

Comment: Because Prettier does it "better" and if you are working with the a team they don't need to buy JetBrain product to format the same.

Comment: The thing is, I work in a company while I'm studying. I'm a supporter of Prettier, but they asked why they should use Prettier if they simply can use the IntelliJ Code Format because all the developers in the company use IntelliJ. I searched for comparisons and what Prettier could do better, but I didn't really find anything useful. Making it "better" is not a good reason without concrete examples.

Comment: Prettier is independent tool and can be run via a command line. You are not tight to InteliJ, so you can use any editor you like and still format your code in a consistent way. Plus don't forget that InteliJ is not for free, maybe you are using the free version now that you are studying but in real world you will have to pay for it.

Answer (score 0):

The set of code style and formatting rules provided by IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm is much more flexible and wider then one by Prettier. Therefore, for some code style settings Prettier can't offer an alternative and you just have to use IntelliJ IDEA/WebStorm.